# Меняющийся div на весь экран

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Представьте себе обычную листалку на сайте. Картинка, одна за другой меняются в определенном div'е, с каким ни будь эффектом листания. Еще с низу ссылки, при нажатии на которые, выходит определенная картинка (5я или 10я). Хочется немного большего.

Пробовал сделать такое для всей страницы.. и тут просто ступор. Хотел div сделать растянутый на весь экран, который меняется, с таким каким ни будь эффектом. (div - фоновый рисунок и 1-2 div внутри)

Ест-но гугль не помог. Может кто помочь кодом? Ну или в крайнем случае посоветовать что либо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот гляньте тут:  [Коллекция эффектов переходов для страниц](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1761)
Демо: [ТУТ](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les1761/demo/index.html)

Comment: Оно самое!!1